# Series convergence for sequence of zeroes and ones

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove for $a_n$$\in${0,1}, $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n}$$ always converges for all $n\inℕ$.

I took the extreme examples, where the sequence is either all zeroes or all ones. If $a_n$ is a sequence of zeroes, then $S_n$ (sequence of partial sums) will be zero. If $a_n$ is a sequence of ones, then

$$S_1=\frac12$$
$$S_2=\frac12+\frac14$$
$$S_3=\frac12+\frac14+\frac18$$ and on. Therefore, in this case, $S_n\le\frac12+\frac12=1$

So $0\le S_n\le1$

Is this a correct approach?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.

Comment: Do you know the result that a bounded monotone increasing sequence of real numbers converges?

Comment: Yes. So I showed that the sequence of partial sums is bounded. And since $a_n\ge 0$ for all n, then the sequence is monotonically increasing?

Comment: Yes. However, what you’ve written here doesn’t actually show that the sequence of partial sums is bounded. Hang on a bit, and I’ll write something up.

Comment: Can you please clarify?

Comment: You’ve shown that $S_1,S_2$, and $S_3$ are less than $1$, but you’ve not done so in a way that obviously generalizes to prove that all $S_n\le 1$.

Comment: I see, I have to be more general by using induction. Thank you!

Comment: You can use induction, or you can do what I did in my answer. Let me know if you want me to add the inductive argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that the sequence of partial sums is bounded in the extreme case of the constant $1$ sequence, just use the formula for the sum of a finite geometric progression, which I’ve actually derived here:

Let $$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}\;;$$ then

$$\begin{align*}
\frac12S_n&=\frac12\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^{k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{k=2}^{n+1}\frac1{2^k}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac1{2^k}\right)-\frac12\\
&=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}\right)+\frac1{2^{n+1}}-\frac12\\
&=S_n+\frac1{2^{n+1}}-\frac12\;.
\end{align*}$$

Now solve for $S_n$:

$$\frac12S_n=\frac12-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\;,$$ so $$S_n=1-\frac1{2^n}<1\;.$$

Now for the general case you have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{a_k}{2^k}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2^k}<1\;.$$

Comment: Much better approach, thank you for all your help

Comment: @Alti: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the sequence of $b_n=\frac{a_n}{2^n}$ is nonnegative, it suffices to find a dominating sequence whose series converges. In particular, $b_n\leq \frac1{2^n}$ for all $n$, so since the geometric series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2^n}$$ converges (to $1$), then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$ also converges.